# Free IPA - Replacing expired 3rd party domain certificate

Tags: freeipa

I'm using FreeIPA version 4.5

My 3rd party domain certificate expired. Can I just copy the new crt & key files over the old ones (they have the same file names) and restart ipa?

Or do I need to use the ipa-server-certinstall command to install the new certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I ran into was that I could not start the ipa service because of an expired certificate. To get around this issue I completed the following steps:

- Changed the server date to a date prior to the cert expiration date
  by executing: `date -s "1 FEB 2019 00:00:00"`
- Started the ipa service by executing: `systemctl start ipa`
- Changed the server date back to the current date by executing: `date
  -s "17 FEB 2019 11:45:00"`

After completing those steps I was then able to execute:

 
`ipa-server-certinstall -p DMPassword -w -d /etc/pki/private/mycert.pem /etc/pki/public/mycert.crt`

where the mycert.pem & mycert.crt files are the new key and cert.

Finally I restarted the ipa service by executing: `systemctl restart ipa`

IPA is now running as expected with the new certificates.